# How to - sql update sort order after delete

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The code below works fine but I'm wondering if there are alternative ways of handling this. Basically, after removing an entry, I need to update the sort order.

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM `ee_blog_category` WHERE id = '.$category_id;
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_error($con)){
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
// update cat sort
$i = 1;
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `ee_blog_category` ORDER BY `sort`';
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $sql1 = 'UPDATE `ee_blog_category` SET `sort` = '.$i.' WHERE `id` = '.$row['id'];
    mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: you can calculate in an update like `set sort=sort-1`. This way you don't need to loop.

Comment: How did you determine the values of the `sort` column in the first place, before you updated them? Your update simply sets them to the same as their `id` values. You could just `SORT BY id` and call it a day. Nobody will ever know your `id` values aren't contiguous -- some have been `DELETE`d --  unless you tell them.

Comment: I prefer to have a separate sort column, on insert total rows are counted and add +1 and make the newest entry the last in the sort.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a different (I think better) way:

1. get the sort value of the deleted item (of course before you delete it).
2. Update all the items which have a greater sort value with `sort=sort-1`

In your case this would be something like:

```
$sql = "Select sort from ee_blog_category where id=$category_id";
// execute, fetch, catch errors...
$sort_original = $row['sort'];

// now update all the others
$sql = "UPDATE ee_blog_category SET sort=sort-1 where sort > $sort_original"; // maybe add a filter here (by group f.e.)
// execute, check for errors.
```

**NOTE:**
You could be open to sql-injection.
Better use prepared statements!

Comment: Ok, thanks, yes the $category_id is obtained from a prepared statement

Comment: Is this solution accounting for the fact that a category has just been removed, and it is now updating the sort of the remaining rows?

Comment: it is sorting everthing "above" the deleted one. Hangon, I made a miss... I edit..

Comment: I've edited the answer, because I forgot to add `where sort>$sort_original`.

Answer (score 0):

Use variables and put this in one statement:

```
SET @s := 0;
UPDATE `ee_blog_category`
    SET `sort` = (@s := @s + 1)
    ORDER BY sort;
```

In practice, you only need to do this for ids bigger than the one deleted.  If you are only deleting one row:

```
UPDATE ee_bloc_cateory
    SET sort = sort - 1
    WHERE sort >= (SELECT MIN(sort) FROM ee_bloc_cateory WHERE id = $deleted_id);
```

You can query for `$deleted_id` or even `$deleted_sort` before doing the deletion.

Comment: this looks confusing.. kind of like keeping things simple and readable..but this is probably a great solution